# PHP Insert Trim box or bleed box into PDF document

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

I have a PDF document that can be any size and I would like to burn in or insert a trim box into that PDF using PHP. Possibly with Imagemagick but do not know the command to run (not sure if one even exists)

I did a lot of searching and havent found anything that answers my question so I am hoping someone may know. I would provide code but I do not even know what commands to use to provide any code of what I have tried. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a framework that allows you to alter an existant pdf. 
Zend-pdf is a framework like that.  http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.html

Comment: So, you only want to resize the pdfs to a fixed size, having the end result like **an image**? It would be an image (or maybe a serie of images), not a pdf anymore. You are ok with that?

Answer (score 0):

After going through lots of cropping tools using command line, nothing was working perfectly as I expected. I tried Ghostscript and Imagemagick, they have the script but it doesn't work as I want, so my favorite tool now for this and it works perfectly it called Briss and its a free tool that you can find [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/briss/patches/2/) as an example for the command, you will need to call 
this command using PHP :

```
 java -jar briss-0.9.jar -s original.pdf -d cropped.pdf -c 0.11/0.08/0.11/0.08:0.11/0.08/0.11/0.08
```

And this is an explanation for each value from the left in inch

```
 First  param : Upper  space for even 
 Second param : Right  space for even 
 Third  param : bottom space for even 
 Forth  param : left   space for even

 Sixth   param : Upper  space for odd 
 Seventh param : Right  space for odd 
 Eighth  param : bottom space for odd 
 Ninth   param : left   space for odd
```

Hope it helps