# PHP - Create a PDF Trimbox

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm using **FPDF** to create PDF files. But I need the file to have trimbox settings. How to do that.

The trimbox needs to be 210mm x 297mm and the file has cropmarks of 7mm so the actual size of the file is bigger... 214mm x 311mm

*I found PDFLib but there is no budget to buy this server-side software.*

Comment: What have you tried? What is your specific programming problem with FPDF? Stackoverflow is not a croudsourcing service for finding libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wish to stay the full php code route, you could use this derivate of FPDF: [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) by [Nicola Asuni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721851/nicola-asuni)

he supports setting the page format and specifying values for trimbox, mediabox, cropbox, bleedbox and artbox as evidenced in some of his examples. The following code is [one of his examples](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_060/) and shows it in action.

even though [its github repository](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf) says TCPDF should be considered obsolete, the successor's repository [tc-lib-pdf](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf) says to not use it yet because it still being under development, so for now it's probably a safer bet to use the old one and keep tabs on the new one for any developments.

```
<?php
//============================================================+
// File name   : example_060.php
// Begin       : 2010-05-17
// Last Update : 2013-05-14
//
// Description : Example 060 for TCPDF class
//               Advanced page settings.
//
// Author: Nicola Asuni
//
// (c) Copyright:
//               Nicola Asuni
//               Tecnick.com LTD
//               www.tecnick.com
//               info@tecnick.com
//============================================================+

/**
* Creates an example PDF TEST document using TCPDF
* @package com.tecnick.tcpdf
* @abstract TCPDF - Example: Advanced page settings.
* @author Nicola Asuni
* @since 2010-05-17
*/

// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 060');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 060', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 20);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set page format (read source code documentation for further information)
$page_format = array(
    'MediaBox' => array ('llx' => 0, 'lly' => 0, 'urx' => 210, 'ury' => 297),
    'CropBox' => array ('llx' => 0, 'lly' => 0, 'urx' => 210, 'ury' => 297),
    'BleedBox' => array ('llx' => 5, 'lly' => 5, 'urx' => 205, 'ury' => 292),
    'TrimBox' => array ('llx' => 10, 'lly' => 10, 'urx' => 200, 'ury' => 287),
    'ArtBox' => array ('llx' => 15, 'lly' => 15, 'urx' => 195, 'ury' => 282),
    'Dur' => 3,
    'trans' => array(
        'D' => 1.5,
        'S' => 'Split',
        'Dm' => 'V',
        'M' => 'O'
     ),
    'Rotate' => 90,
    'PZ' => 1,
);

// Check the example n. 29 for viewer preferences

// add first page ---
$pdf->AddPage('P', $page_format, false, false);
$pdf->Cell(0, 12, 'First Page', 1, 1, 'C');

// add second page ---
$page_format['Rotate'] = 270;
$pdf->AddPage('P', $page_format, false, false);
$pdf->Cell(0, 12, 'Second Page', 1, 1, 'C');

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_060.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be two tools for doing this:

Briss (as described in this stackoverflow post):
[PHP Insert Trim box or bleed box into PDF document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216901/php-insert-trim-box-or-bleed-box-into-pdf-document)

pdfboxer by nicknux (as described in this stackoverflow post):
[Ghostscript: adding BleedBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605438/ghostscript-adding-bleedbox)

Hope one of these two helps.